# как сделать чтобы массив принимал следующие значения?

Tags: c++

Пусть А - множество всех делителей числа 9, В - множество всех делителей числа 12 в пределах от 9 до 100.

```
int main()
    {
        int SIZE = 0;
        int SIZE_1 = 0;
        int SIZE_0 = 0;
        int x, y;
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        int* Set = new int[max_SIZE];
        int* Set_1 = new int[max_SIZE];
        int* Set_0 = new int[max_SIZE];
        cout << "Введите размер первого множества, которая должна быть сгенерирована" << endl;
        cin >> SIZE;
        GenerationSet(Set, SIZE);
        ShowSet(Set, SIZE);
        cout << "Введите размер второго множества, которая должна быть сгенерирована" << endl;
        cin >> SIZE_1;
        GenerationSet(Set_1, SIZE_1);
        ShowSet(Set_1, SIZE_1);

void GenerationSet(int* Set, int SIZE)
{
    int i = 0;
    Set[i] = 2000 - rand() % 1000;
    int temp;
    while (i < SIZE)
    {
        temp = 1000 - rand() % 2000;
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            if (temp == Set[j]) continue;
        i++;
        Set[i] = temp;
    }
    SortSet(Set, SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста опишите ясней свой вопрос, приведите примеры, свои неудачные попытки решить проблему.

Comment: Нужно чтобы в set были такие числа: 9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90,99; в set1:12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96

Comment: Ну так добавляйте эти элементы. Сначала 9, потом 9 * 2, потом 9 * 3 и так пока  9 * i <= 100. С 12 аналогично.

Comment: так `for (int i = 0; i * 9 <= 100; i++) {
        Set[i] = i;
    }`?

Comment: начинать надо с 1 и вам же надо, чтобы элементы в `Set` были не `1 2 3 4 5` а `9 18 27`. Зачем тогда пишите просто `Set[i] = i`?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        Set[i] = i*9;
    }`когда начинаю с 1 выбивает ошибку сам дебаггер

Comment: Я же написал начать с `1`, то есть `int i = 1`, само условие правильное.

Comment: когда начинаю с 1 выбивает ошибку сам дебаггер

Comment: В общем `for (int i = 1; i * 9 <= 100; i++) { Set[i - 1] = i * 9; }`